# Why did Airi (the A.I.) disapear?

Tags: robotics-notes

When the Real Airi awakens, the A.I. Airi disappears.

Was her disappearance programmed to be triggered by Airi's awakening, or did it have something to do with some glitch in the Iru-O around Christmas?

Comment: By "Real Airi," are you referring to Sister Centipede (Geji-nee) or Airi Yukifune when she wakes up? Please consider providing a reference point (episode or chapter) so we have a better idea of what you're referring to.

Comment: @Krazer: Must've been Yukifune. Now that I think about it, she does indeed not appear anymore after Airi awakens.